# Github action for auto labeler

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to automate applying label to the GitHub PRs.

I came across this awesome [GitHub Action](https://github.com/actions/labeler) I am not able to understand on where to put labels and `any[]` or `all[]`

This is what I have tried so far -

```
# This workflow will triage pull requests and apply a label based on the
# paths that are modified in the pull request.
#
# To use this workflow, you will need to set up a .github/labeler.yml
# file with configuration.  For more information, see:
# https://github.com/actions/labeler

name: Labeler
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  label:
  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/labeler@v2
      with:
        repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        sync-labels: true
        
    - name: Applying labels.
      deployment:
      - any: ['deployment/backend-stack/deployment.yaml']
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/labeler) you need to have two files in your `.github/` folder:

- actual **workflow** is defined in `.github/workflows/labeler.yml`
- **configuration** is set in `.github/labeler.yml`

Difference of the key words `any` and `all`:

- any: match ALL globs against ANY changed path
- all: match ALL globs against ALL changed paths

### Example

#### .github/workflows/labeler.yml

```yaml
name: Labeler
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  label:
  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/labeler@v2
      with:
        repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        sync-labels: true
```

#### .github/labeler.yml

```
deployment:
- any: ['deployment/backend-stack/deployment.yaml']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some aspirations with [this commit](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/commit/17ef0aea35ab0bff05da3731f5ad4aa2f484bf8d), basically the labeler config is in `.github/labeler.yml`.